# Even with 'HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead', where does HttpClient store the response?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Even with using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` like this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myserver.com");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "huge_file.bin");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

As soon as `SendAsync` is called, HttpClient issues a GET request. This can be seen with Fiddler.

Under the hood, where does the underlying HttpClient actually store the the request response? Is it in memory? If it's in memory, what if the response is really huge, couldn't that be problem? In my tests, it does not seem to be in memory.
Is it maybe in non-user memory, like in the kernel memory? I'm not familiar how does the network things work internally when downloading data.

Note that I'm **not** asking about consuming the response content by calling for example `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. I'm asking how does HttpClient reads and stores the response internally, before I start to consume it by calling `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` for example.

Comment: It doesn't store it anywhere, the response hasn't been sent by the server until you call `ReadAs...`

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately it does not work like that. As soon as you call `SendAsync`, HttpClient will issue a GET request. You can see that clearly in Fiddler.

Comment: Yes it issues the request, but is it actually showing all the bytes being received in the response? In any case, Fiddler is a transparent proxy, which is probably going to fully cache requests and responses in order to parse them. Try using Wireshark and watch the actual network packets, and you will see that the response stream is not fully read until you call `ReadAsStream` and actually read the bytes off the stream.

Comment: From an client-server communication point of view, I didn't realize a client makes the server wait for returning data. I thought once a request is made, the server keeps returning data without waiting for the client to read. I guess it has to do with how sockets work.

Comment: That's how TCP works, it waits for an ACK after a certain amount of data. It might be more than just the headers though.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for confirming, makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't store it anywhere if you use `ResponseHeadersRead`. The response hasn't been fully sent by the server until you call `ReadAs...`.

As far as seeing the request in Fiddler: yes the request is issued, but is it actually showing all the bytes being received in the response?

In any case, Fiddler is a transparent proxy, which is probably going to fully cache requests and responses in order to parse them. Try using Wireshark and watch the actual network packets, and you will see that the response stream is not fully read until you call `ReadAsStream` and actually read the bytes off the stream.

That's just how TCP works (HTTP runs on TCP sockets): it waits for an `ACK` after a certain amount of data. It might be more than just the headers though, as TCP commonly pushes through more than one packet before waiting for an `ACK`.

If you don't read the data after a long enough amount of time, the server will just break the connection.

Comment: and if i use ResponseContentRead, this is cached in the memory?

Comment: Yes correct, the whole thing is buffered